# What does this angular-translate loading error mean?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have this error but I can't understand what it's saying

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=TrackingApp&p1=Typ…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1)
```

link to error: [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=TrackingApp&p1=Error:%20%5Bng:areq%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Sb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:19:510)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20tb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:20:78)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Function.ab.$$annotate%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:173:482)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:36:147)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:34:498)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:35:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ecare/js/libs/angular-translate.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ecare/js/libs/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js' %}"></script>
```

These links have been checked to be correct

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Here is how I injected dependencies:

```
var trackingApp = angular.module('TrackingApp', ['controllers', 'directives', 'factories', 'filters', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
angular.module('factories', []);
angular.module('controllers', []);
angular.module('directives', []);
angular.module('filters', []);

//Translations
trackingApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {
        var path_to_json = $('body').data('path-translate').split('en_us.json')[0];



    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: path_to_json,// path to translations files
        suffix: '.json'// suffix, currently- extension of the translations
    });
//checked that path is correct until here. If I remove the following single line, the app has no error (but not translated)...
        $translateProvider.uses('es_es');
        //.fallbackLanguage('en_us')
        // .useLocalStorage();
    });
trackingApp.run(['CommonData', 'CommonUtils', 'Visibility', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$filter', '$translate',
    function(CommonData, CommonUtils, Visibility, $rootScope, $http, $window, $filter, $translate) {
      //app's code here ...

});
```

HTML:

```
    <section class="content-header">
        <h2 class="content-title">
            <div ng-if="!shipment.ordered_phase && api_data.order.tracking.length > 1" translate>
                Shipment #{{getShipmentIndex(shipment)}}
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!shipment.ordered_phase && api_data.order.tracking.length == 1" translate>
                Shipment Tracking
            </div>
            <div ng-if="shipment.ordered_phase || api_data.order.tracking.length == 0" translate>
                Order Status
            </div>
        </h2>
    </section>
```

Comment: It looks like you've defined the TrackingApp module before its dependencies.

Comment: It's mostly related to angular-translate. When I comment out the line `$translateProvider.uses('es_es')` the error goes away. Am I supposed to define angular-translate in a different order?